# How to create a branch of an old revision with TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a repository where in revision 1 the folders trunk, branches and tags were added.
The source was kept in trunk. Revision 7 happened, and development continued up to revision 16.
Now I have to continue to work on revision 7, so I want to create a branch off of revision 7.

Here is how I tried to do this: Using TortoiseSVN, I select trunk in the repository browser, open "Show log", select revision 7 and right-click "Create branch/tag from revision".
The Copy (Branch / Tag) dialog appears with FROM-URL set to trunk and I enter .../branches/new_branch_name as the To-URL.
"Specific revision in repository" is checked and set to 7.

Now I get an error saying "Path ...../trunk does not exist in revision 7".
But trunk was definitely created in revision 1 and if I look at the changed files of revision 7 in the "Show log" dialog, I can see that the files are added/modified in trunk.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does branches exist in the repository?

Comment: yes, it does. Was also created back in revision 1.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

- Open the repository browser.
- Go to the root directory of the repository.
- Click the "revision" button (it says "HEAD") and from the dialogue select the revision in question
- Right drag-and-drop the "trunk" directory to the "branches" directory and select "Copy and rename item to here".
- Type in the name of the new directory.
- Write a log message.

Comment: Instead of right drag-and-dropping, you can also right-click on the item, choose 'copy to', and then type in the destination path. Others steps as described.

Comment: This won't work if the destination folder doesn't exist in the old revision. for that case, use the "show log" method detailed in another answer

Answer (score 32):

[image]

1. Open repo browser
2. Right click trunk
3. Choose "Show log"
4. Right click revision you want to branch from
5. Choose "Create branch/tag from revision"
6. Set your To path (e.g. branches/MyBranch)

Comment: Like the screenshot. Worth a thousand words.

Comment: True that, a picture is worth a thousand words and the exact picture that we wanted is like a million words. Thanks again Luis Perez

Answer (score 9):

Open the "show log" Dialog and right click a log entry to open the "Create tag/branch"-Dialog.

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted answer, because if you start browsing an entire old version of the repository then the tag structure you want to copy/rename to may not exist.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution:

- Check out old revision
- from your working copy, create a branch

It seems that this must be done using a working copy and not directly in the repository (browser).